# how to quit a buf in vim

Tags: vim

let's say currently there are two buffers in my vim session, and I want to close the current buffer which is under edit in order to switch the other buffer and edit it . using

```
:q
```

will quit the whole vim rather than a buffer .  so my question is are there any commands can close the current buffer under editing and automatically switch to  the next buffer in the buffer list .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just doing a

```
:bd
```

should do it.

**Edit:** You can delete specific buffers as well using this command.

Get a list of your current buffers by entering:

```
:ls
```

This will give you something like:

```
1 #    "ap22_linux_build.sh.log"      line 87
2      "httpd-2.2.14-2010011600-linux32-g.build_log" line 4207
3 %a   "~/.bashrc"                    line 1
```

Take the relevant number and enter it before the bd command, so entering

```
: 2 bd
```

will delete the second buffer.

Answer (score 4):

:bd (buffer delete) or :n (next)

The latter offers the advantage of being able to go back to the first file with :p (previous)

Answer (score 2):

Theres also :bw which wipes the buffer as well. Eg. :bd will remove the buffer but you can get back to it if you hit ctrl-6.

I also really like bufexplorers 'd' key mapping in the buffer viewer, if your like me and get loads of buffers open its a quick way to go through and remove ones you dont need any more. 
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42